# React async/await usage - Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

Tags: async-await, react-redux, promise, reduce, dispatch

I am adding data to an addItem array using reducers.

I want to wait until the item is actually added before going forward..I have implemented it as follows

```
const [addItems, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'add':
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: state.length,
          data: action.data
        }
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}, []);

const linkDataHandler = async(samplesData, test, e) => {
    
    const isSelected =  e.target.checked;

    await callDispatch(samplesData.id, test.testList.id, isSelected) 
    .then( r =>{
    //do something
    }});
  
    };

const callDispatch = (sampleId, testId, checked) => {
      
      const linkedData = {
        sampleId: sampleId,
        TestId: testId,
        isSelected: checked
      };
  
      dispatch({
        type: "add",
        data: linkedData
      });
    };
```

function linkDataHandler is called on a checkbox onChange() event.

It is giving me

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

Answer (score 0):

I have re-written callDispatch as follows. Since it is expected to return a promise

```
const callDispatch = (sampleId, testId, checked) => {
               

      const linkedData = {
        sampleId: sampleId,
        TestId: testId,
        isSelected: checked
      };
  
      return Promise.resolve(
      dispatch({
        type: "add",
        data: linkedData
      }));
    };
```